# Android 4.0.3 not getting boot in AVD

Tags: android

I'm newbee to Android. I have set up all things in the android site to run Hello world program. I've installed the latest platform Android 4.0.3.. I've created an AVD and when I tried to start the avd, a screen showing ANDROID runs. I've been waiting for more than 2 hours to get the menu in the avd, but nothing worked up.. Can anyone help me out to find the problem??

[Note: I'm using Pentium 4 processor running in windows XP]

Comment: try to restart the emulator or change the resolution for the emulator

Comment: well, that too didn't work !!

Answer (score 1):

you must have install X86 atom emulator...
which requires haxm(hardware accelerated execution manager) which requires intel vt supported processors, and pentium 4 does not support virtual technology.

so either try using another emulator or change your processor.....

[check installation instruction for haxm here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows/)

[and check your processor capabilty here](http://ark.intel.com/)

Answer (score 0):

4.0.3 usually takes a long time to boot for me as well, running on 4 GB RAM on Core i5. I would recommend working with a lower version such as 2.3.3 (which mobiles support as well). But here are a few general steps to make avd run faster (assuming you are using Eclipse):

1. Run > Run Configurations > Target. Check the "disable boot animations" and in the additional options, specify "-scale 0.5".
2. Enable snapshots. This allows you to save the running emulator and instantly load it at a later time (so you only have to boot up once).
   Go to AVD editor and edit the AVD. Check the "Snapshot Enabled" check box.

Answer (score 0):

Well just restart your eclipse. If the praoblem persists then check if  you have provided any virtual sdcard file with right permission.